# Change ggplot scale labels to original values after using a log transformation

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've got an `exponentially` distributed variable that I'd like to plot using `ggplot2`. I'm going to take the `log` of the variable.  However, instead of having the axis label be the `log` format, I'd like it to be the original `exponentially` distributed values. Here's an example.

```
set.seed(1000)

aero_df <- 
data_frame(
    x = rnorm(100,100,99),
    y = sample(c('dream on',
                 'dude looks like a lady'),
               100,
               replace = T)) %>% 
    mutate(x = x*x,
           log_x = log(x)) %>% 
    gather(key,value,-y)

aero_plot <-   ggplot(aero_df,aes(value,color = y,fill = y))+
    geom_density(show.legend = F)+
    facet_wrap(key~y,scales = 'free')
```

I'd like to have the `x` variable labels on the `log_x`.

```
aero_plot
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I started of with this, but the issue here is that you can see the normal log_x labels also in the x plots.

```
ticks <- c(3,6,9,12)
logticks <- c(exp(9),exp(10),exp(11))

ggplot(aero_df,aes(value,color = y,fill = y))+
  geom_density(show.legend = F)+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(ticks,logticks), labels = c(ticks,log(logticks))) +
  facet_wrap(key~y,scales = 'free')
```

Comment: What I was looking for - didn't ask very well - is a way to change the labels for each facet in a `ggplot`. It looks like your answer will provide that, so I accepted it.

Comment: I was too struggling with getting manual labels per facet. This solution does not give full control yet, but I doubt that control per facet is even possible.

Answer (score 1):

ggplot's `scale_x_log10` to the rescue, maybe? I'm not 100% sure I understand your question, because I didn't understand your example code. Hopefully this is what you mean...

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(1000)

aero_df <- 
  data_frame(
    x = rnorm(100,100,99),
    y = sample(c('dream on',
                 'dude looks like a lady'),
               100,
               replace = T))

aero_plot <- ggplot(aero_df,aes(x,color = y,fill = y)) +
  geom_density(show.legend = F) +
  scale_x_log10() +
  facet_wrap(~y,scales = 'free')

print(aero_plot)
```

[image]